# How to display post tags

Tags: posts, functions, tags

I'm converting an HTML template into a wordpress theme and I'm having some trouble displaying the post tags within the functions.php file. What I would like to do is add the following code into the functions file with the HTML code. I have been trying for a few days now and I have already been to the codex but nothing I try is working.

```
<div class="tags">
<a href="#" rel="tag">tag 1</a> <a href="#" rel="tag">tag 2</a> <a href="#" rel="tag">tag 3</a> <a href="#" rel="tag">tag 4</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Sorry, but you are not providing enough informations to give an clear answer. The functions.php file is supposed to include custom theme helper functions and no direct html output. Where do you exactly want the output to happen? You want to output a list of assigned tags on a singles post view?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I want the output to be in the single post. The tags you assign to each a post.

Comment: Through the functions file? Or through any file?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are searching for the [get_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) function. You would need to place it into the `single-post.php` (or `single.php` if your theme doesn't have a `single-post.php`) (to find the right template file you can always look up at  [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)).

To echo a list of tags with the aboved linked function you would need to use something like:

```
<?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>
<div class="tags">
<?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if you think it was helpfull. Have a nice evening. :-)

Comment: Doesn't work from the functions file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to add post tags after the content on single posts only using [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter in a custom function from your functions file. Uses [`the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

```
function tags_after_single_post_content($content) {

if( is_singular('post') && is_main_query() ) {

$tags = the_tags('<div class="entry-meta">Tagged with: ',' • ','</div><br />'); 

$content .= $content . $tags;
    }
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'tags_after_single_post_content' );
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Correct code:

```
function tags_after_single_post_content($content) {
  $posttags = get_the_tags();
  if ($posttags) {
    $array = [];
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $array[] = '<a href="/tag/' . $tag->slug . '/">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }
    $content .= 'Tags: ' . implode(', ', $array) . '<br>';
  }

  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'tags_after_single_post_content' );
```

Reason [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/157077/57319) answer is wrong because [the_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) is should be used inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and the_tags return nothing so other code is doing nothing. In this answer [get_the_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) return array of tag instances so we can append them to content.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to WPSE. Could you please edit your post to explain _why_ this is the correct code? Code only answers are discouraged here as they don't teach anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Displays a list of tags with links to each one and a specific class for each tag:

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
       $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

       $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
       $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Link to the source of your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this code in the end of functions.php file:

```php
function tags_after_single_post_content($content) {
  $posttags = get_the_tags();
  if ($posttags) {
    $array = [];
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      $array[] = '<a href="/tag/' . $tag->slug . '/">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }
    $content .= 'Tags: ' . implode(', ', $array) . '<br>';
  }

  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'tags_after_single_post_content' );
```

Comment: That looks like you've just copied Artem's answer. Have you changed anything?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).